# Django filter model with timestamp

Tags: django, filter, model, timestamp

I have the following models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)

class Data(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Given a single user, I would like to know how I can filter using timestamp. For example:

Obtain the data from user1, between now and 1 hour ago.

I have the current timestamp with `now = time.time()`, also I have 1 hour ago using `hour_ago = now-3600`

I would like to obtain the Data that has a timestamp between these two values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [***range***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#range) to obtain data between two values.

**You can use range anywhere you can use BETWEEN in SQL — for dates, numbers and even characters.**

e.g.

```
Data.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(start, end))
```

from docs:

```
import datetime 
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1) 
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31) 
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__gte` which is termed as `greater than or equal to` and  `__lte` refers `less than or equal to`
So try this,

```
Data.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=hour_ago,timestamp__lte=now)
```

You can find similar examples in [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#gte)